# First deploy fails in Capistrano 3 with a /var/www/XXX permission error

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3

I am running the first deploy to a machine via `cap staging deploy`. As of Cap3, `deploy:setup` is no longer needed. Yet, strangely, I get a mkdir permissions error:

```
 INFO[cb348f12] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /var/www/myapp/shared /var/www/myapp/releases on ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
 DEBUG[cb348f12] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /var/www/myapp/shared /var/www/myapp/releases
 DEBUG[cb348f12]    mkdir: 
 DEBUG[cb348f12]    cannot create directory ‘/var/www’
 DEBUG[cb348f12]    : Permission denied
 DEBUG[cb348f12]    
 DEBUG[cb348f12]    mkdir: 
 DEBUG[cb348f12]    cannot create directory ‘/var/www’
 DEBUG[cb348f12]    : Permission denied
 DEBUG[cb348f12]    
 cap aborted!
 SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com: mkdir exit status: 1
```

Of course, I could go an create and chmod that directory myself, but that's not the point. Cap3 is supposed to take care of that itself. I'm confused why it doesn't do that. I should also note that I had this same setup succeed before with another machine (though that was "production" environment).

Here are some basic settings in my deploy.rb:

```
 set :application, "myapp"
 set :user, 'ec2-user'
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating the following directory structure: `/var/www/myapp/shared/var/www/myapp/releases`
try: `/var/www/myapp/releases`

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Re-reading your question, I found that you already know how to create folder on server and set permission.

> Cap3 is supposed to take care of that itself. I'm confused why it
>   doesn't do that

Nope. Cap3 cannot create a folder on server automatically, if the user provided to Cap3 does not have previledges to create the folder. There is no magic here just unix permissions.

In your case the user your have provided `ec2-user` does not have permission to create folder in `/var` which causes the error.

---

Original answer

Check whether `/var/www` folder exists on your server. If it does not, then create that folder and set its ownership to `ec2-user` so that Capistrano can create any other folders as necessary during the deployment.

`sudo mkdir -p /var/www
sudo chown ec2-user:ec2-user /var/www`

With the above commands run, try deploying again with capistrano. Permission error should now be gone.

Comment: ec2-user can run under sudo. afaik (or remember), cap3 promises to apply sudo for mkdir (cap2 didn't do that)

Comment: "The second part of this topic is that our deploy user needs to be authorised to work in the deployment directory, on the server. That means we need to be able to work, ideally without sudo (none of the default Capistrano recipes expect sudo to be available), or for your custom recipes, you will need to have configured passwordless sudo. Configuring sudo to give some users access to come commands under some circumstances is beyond the scope of this documentation"

from http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/authentication-and-authorisation/ clarifies my point.

Comment: I do have passwordless sudo

Comment: for creating directory, capistrano does not use 'sudo'. It just assumes that the `ec2-user` will be able to create a directory in `/var/www` without any special permission. So you need to change the ownership of `/var/www` to `ec2-user`